# toggle menu in react only responds to first click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to make a toggle menu in react, the menu opens on first click but nothing happens on following clicks(it should close on second click), however it doesn't recognize any more clicks after the first one.

```
const RightMenu = () => {
  const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = e => {
    const el = document.getElementById("menu");
    if (menuOpen === false) {
      el.style.display = "block";
      setMenuOpen(true);
      console.log("menu opened: ");
      console.log(el);
    }
    if (menuOpen === true) {
      el.style.display = "none";
      setMenuOpen(false);
      console.log("menu closed");
      console.log(el);
    }
  };
return (
    <div style={style ? style : ""}>
      <div
        className="text-center"
        style={{
          borderTopLeftRadius: "10px",
          borderTopRightRadius: "10px",
          cursor: "pointer",
          display: "block"
        }}
        onClick={e => handleClick(e)}
      > Toggle div
      </div>
<div className="" id="menu" style={{ display: "none" }}>
menu to show
</div>
 );
};
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems to work as expected without changing your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-jang-hwu38

Answer (score 0):

I tried you code on Repl and it worked fine.

```
import React, {Component, useState } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
const App = () => {
const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);

const handleClick = e => {
    const el = document.getElementById("menu");
    if (menuOpen === false) {
        el.style.display = "block";
        setMenuOpen(true);
        console.log("menu opened: ");
        console.log(el);
    }
    if (menuOpen === true) {
        el.style.display = "none";
        setMenuOpen(false);
        console.log("menu closed");
        console.log(el);
    }
};
return ( < div >
    <  div className = "text-center"
    style = {
        {
            borderTopLeftRadius: "10px",
            borderTopRightRadius: "10px",
            cursor: "pointer",
            display: "block"
        }
    }
    onClick = {
        e => handleClick(e)
    } >
    Toggle div <
    /div> < div className = "form-group" id = "menu" style = { { display: "none" } } >  menu to show < /div> < /div>
);
};
export default App;
```